# Are there any hypermodern openings for white

Tags: opening

I just want to ask if there is any kind of hypermodern opening for white.
For black, i usually play benko gambit and alekhine defense, so preferably, I am opting for a tactical opening

Comment: Reti opening is considered hypermodern...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A hypermodern opening in chess is one whose strategy controls the centre from the outside. For instance fianchettoed bishops [b3 or g3 followed by Bb2 or Bg2] can do this. Central pawn moves are delayed till later on.

Specifically a hypermodern opening for white could be 1. b3 and then 2. Bb2 called Larsen's Opening or the Nimzowitsch attack. The idea is to use the Bb2 bishop along its diagonal, especially if black castles kingside. For instance the opening could go:

```
  [FEN ""]
  1. b3 e5 2. Bb2 Nc6 3. e3 d5 4. Bb5 Bd6 5. f4 Qh4+ 6. g3 Qe7 *
```

This is quite a well known opening position in Larsen's attack. White's move 5. f4 is important - white is attacking black's centre. A common continuation is for white to eventually castle o-o-o queenside and black to castle kingside with equal chances of mutual attack. Larsen was a GM who used this opening with great success with one exception! His loss to Spassky: http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1128831

Another hypermodern opening is to play 1. Nc3 and 2. Nf3 as white and provoke black into chasing your knights with black's pawns. This is rather humorously called the Napoleon attack after Napoleon's horses!! Though I am pretty sure that he never played it!

Another hypermodern opening is the King's Indian Attack - a King's Indian formation as white:

```
   [FEN ""]
   1. Nf3  Nf6  2. g3 d5 3. Bg2 c5 4. d3 Nc6 5. O-O e5 6. Nbd2 Be7 7. e4 O-O 8. Qe2 *
```

Fischer used this with success. There are many hypermodern white openings that let black put pawns in the centre to make a target for white to attack. This is a small taste of them here.

Answer (score 5):

Considering hypermodern opening as White is very often just a copy of Black hypermodern strategy with a tempo up, which is mainly based on putting your bishop(s) in fianchetto.
For instance, you have for White, "Larsen opening" 1.b3 or "Réti opening" 1.Cf3 and next 2.g3 or 1.g3.

Also you have sicilian-type opening, which gives you for White : 1.c4

Comment: Bobby Fischer frequently play the King's Indian Attack.

Answer (score 5):

Arguably, the "original" hyper Modern opening was the [Reti opening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9ti_Opening). named after Richard Reti who introduced, or at least popularized it. It was *White's* opening, and began Nf3. If Black responded d5, White might or might not respond c4. Instead, he might play 2. g3, then Bg2 for an early fianchetto and castling.

1. Nf3 has the effect of deterring e5, unless Black first supports it with e.g. d6. But when Black plays Nf6 in the Alekhine, it is after White has played e4, which means that White has the option to chase the knight with e5.

Answer (score 0):

I found this called Czyzewski Opening. (I do not know how, in this case black should react.)

```
  [FEN ""]
  1. e4 e5 2. b3 *
```

Source: http://maciejczyzewski.me/2015/05/05/czyzewski-opening-a-hypermodern-chess-variation.html